# Ajax does not work on dynamically added Select2 select list

Tags: jquery-select2

I need to dynamically add a Select2 dropdown list to my asp.net mvc View.  I add select2 this way all the time, but this is the first time I tried adding one with an ajax call and the ajax call does not happen.  I also tried hiding then showing the element, but it doesn't work that way either.  The only way I can get it to work is if I place it directly on the page and it is part of the DOM when the page loads.  Is there any way that I can dynamically add this control?

```
                    $('#divEmployee').show();
                $('#divEmployee').append('<label>Employees:</label><select id="reqEmployee" class="form-control" name ="reqEmployee" multiple ></select >')
              
                $('#reqEmployee').select2({
                    width: "100%", placeholder: 'Select an Employee', ajax: ({
                        url: "@Url.Action("EmployeeSearch", "Lookup", new { area = "" })", data: function (params) { return { term: params.term, all: !$('#ActiveOnly').is(":checked"), nameAsVal: false, fullName: true, ecid: true } }, delay: 250, dataType: 'json',
                        processResults: function (data) { return { results: data } }
                    }), minimumInputLength: 2
                }).trigger('change');
                $('#reqEmployee').on('change', function () {
                    var value = $('#reqEmployee').val();
                    $('#Employees').val(value);
                });
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Why are you trying to `trigger` change before adding the event handler? Perhaps if you moved the last portion of your example between the `append` and the call to `trigger`?

Comment: You can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vn0u97e2/) .